# matlab vectorization varying array

Tags: arrays, function, variables, matlab, vectorization

Can anyone tell me what the basic idea behind varying rows or columns in a matrix with respect to the row/column number is in matlab? I've been trying to replace all the columns in a given matrix by

```
i=1:101;
V=ones(121,101);
V_t=1000*10.^((i-1)/20);
e=V_arr(1:121)';
V_arr=V; V_arr(:,i)=V_t*e;
```

I know that the error lies in trying to replace a number of columns with respect to all rows, and I've seen an alternative, simpler method using repmat, but I'd like to know if there's a method similar to the one above.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to use matrix multiplication, i.e. a `n-by-1` array multiplied by an `1-by-m` array creates a `n-by-m` array.

For example

```
ii = 1:101; %# 1-by-101
V_t = 1000*10.^((i-1)/20);
ee = ones(121,1); %# 121-by-1

V_arr = ee * V_t;
```